# Rewriting a random sum using conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

I'm currently trying to figure out a proof given in a elementary probability lecture, involving a trick using the conditional probability.

$\mathbf {Assumptions}:$

a) $N$ is a random variable with support $\mathbb{N}_0$.

b) $X_1, X_2,...$ are i.i.d. random variables.

c) $N, X_1, X_2,...$ are independend.

$\mathbf {Problem}:$
I'm citing the proof in the lecture notes. The goal is to rewrite
$$P(X_1 + ...+X_N \leq t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X_1+...+X_N \leq t, N = n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X_1+...+X_N \leq t| N = n) P(N=n)$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X_1+...+X_n \leq t) P(N=n)$$

I understand why the first and the second equation holds, but I'm a bit confused about the third equation, i.e. mainly the step $P(X_1+...+X_N \leq t| N = n) = P(X_1+...+X_n \leq t)$ is what confuses me the most. Intuitively it totally makes sense to me but I'm having problems proving this statement rigorously.

$\mathbf {My Approach}:$ I tried to rewrite
$$P(X_1+...+X_N \leq t| N = n) = \frac{P(X_1+...+X_N \leq t, N = n)}{P(N=n)} =\frac{P(X_1+...+X_n \leq t, N = n)}{P(N=n)} = \frac{P(X_1+...+X_n \leq t) P(N = n)}{P(N=n)} = P(X_1+...+X_n \leq t)$$
In the second equation I used that $\{\omega \in \Omega: X_1+...+X_N \leq t, N = n\} = \{\omega \in \Omega: X_1+...+X_n \leq t, N = n\}$ (Which holds since, we use the intersection with $N=n$). The first equation is just the definition of the conditional probability and the third equation I used the independence of $N, X_1, X_2,...$ Is this proof correct, or am I missing something?

$\mathbf {Question}:$

a) Is this proof above correct, or am I missing something?

b) The second step in the proof cited in the section "Problem" is not really needed, or am I wrong?

c) The equation $P(X_1+...+X_N \leq t| N = n) = P(X_1 + ... + X_n \leq t)$ does only hold if $N, X_1, X_2,...$ are independent right? Is there a way to rewrite $P(X_1 + ... + X_N \leq t)$ if the independence does not hold?

Thanks in advance!
Sorry if this question is kind of dumb...just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me, but even though your proof uses independence, it think the result holds more generally

Comment: @Snildt Oh really? Do you have a hint for me on how to prove that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it in your specific case here, but in my textbook on advanced probability theory it is stated without assuming independence, that if we condition on a random variable assuming some value, we can always just insert that value. The general proof is pretty technical and requires a measure theoretical definition of conditional distributions.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you please give me the name of the book? I'd like to check what they are using. Thanks in advance!